# How do I pass a missing value to feature_columns.bucketized_column()?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a `Dataset` with a column named `my_col`. `my_col` is a positive number which I want to transform into one-hot-encode vector of 5 buckets:

```
fc_my_col = fc.indicator_column(
  fc.bucketized_column(
    fc.numeric_column('my_col'), boundaries=[1000, 2000, 3000, 4000]))
feature_columns = [fc_my_col]
...

inp_layer = fc.feature_columns.input_layer(features_batch, feature_columns)
```

This works fine when `my_col` has a value but some records don't have and I want all 5 buckets indicators to have 0 in that case.

I can fill in a default value for the missing ones, but since `bucketized_column` buckets the whole range of numbers into buckets I'll always fall into one of them..

Can I 'ignore' a bucket? Tell `bucketized_column` to remove 'out of boundaries' maybe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `default_value` as shown below:

```
fc_my_col = fc.indicator_column(
  fc.bucketized_column(
    fc.numeric_column('my_col', default_value=0), boundaries=[1000, 2000, 3000, 4000]))
feature_columns = [fc_my_col]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Comment: Additionally, thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Thanks 杨旭东. But that doesn't exactly solve the problem. If I add a default value to 'my_col', then the bucketized column will fall into one of the bins and then one of the indicators will be on. 
I want to have all indicators off in the case of out-of-boundaries.